# Extract words from a string

Tags: python

Sample Input:

```
'note - Part model D3H6 with specifications X30G and Y2A is having features 12H89.'
```

Expected Output:

```
['D3H6', 'X30G', 'Y2A', '12H89']
```

My code:

```
split_note = re.split(r'[.;,\s]\s*', note)
pattern = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")  
#if pattern.match(ini_str):
for a in n2:
        if pattern.match(a):
            alphaList.append(a)
```

I need to extract all the alpha numeric words from a split string and store them in a list.

The above code is unable to give expected output.

Comment: What are the exact rules of the words you want matched/rejected? Do matching words always end with a number? Do they always contain *some* number? Are they always without lowercase letters? What are ``note``, ``n2`` and ``alphaList`` in your code?

Comment: I forgot to change the names. n2 is split_note. alphaList is created to store extracted alpha numeric words. note will be of nature same as sample input note. They will always be in uppercase and will be of variable length. They can start with an alphabet or number and end with either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can solve the problem:

```
import re 

# input string
stri = "Part model D3H6 with specifications X30 and Y2 is having features 12H89"
# words tokenization
split = re.findall("[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z])|[\'\w\-]+",stri)
# this statment returns words containing both numbers and letters
print([word for word in split if bool(re.match('^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])', word))])

#output: ['D3H6', 'X30', 'Y2', '12H89']
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code is unable to read words ending with an alphabet.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Now it works also for words ending with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

`^` and `$` are meant for the end and beginning of a line, not of a word.
Besides your example words don't include lower case, so why adding `a-z`?

Considering your example, if what you need is to fetch a word that always contains both at least one letter and at least one number and always ends with a number, this is the pattern:

```
\b[0-9A-Z]+\d+\b
```

If it may end with a letter rather than a digit, but still requires at least one digit and one letter,then it gets more complex:

```
\b[0-9A-Z]*\d|[A-Z][0-9A-Z]*\b
```

`\b` stands for a word boundary.